# Implementing backpressure in a transform stream

Tags: node.js, stream, stdin, nodejs-stream

I was reading these docs:
https://nodejs.org/ja/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/

It says:

```
Readable.pipe(Transformable).pipe(Writable);
```

> "Backpressure will be automatically applied, but note that both the
>   incoming and outgoing highWaterMark of the Transform stream may be
>   manipulated and will effect the backpressure system."

I can change the `highWaterMark` this way:

```
export class JSONParser extends stream.Transform {

  constructor() {
    super({objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 3}); // 3 objects is high water mark
  }

}
```

but since it says that both incoming and outgoing `highWaterMark` of the transform stream can be manipulated - how do I change the `highWaterMark` of the incoming/outgoing data? My guess is that this one property controls both levels?

In essence, I am trying to slow the amount of reads in my stream, so that other I/O can be processed. The readable stream in my case is `process.stdin` and `process.stdin` is being piped to a transform stream, which I control. How can I slow the rate of reading from stdin?

Answer (score 0):

For Duplex streams (or Transform streams, which inherit from Duplex), you can set both `readableHighWaterMark` and `writableHighWaterMark` as options. Your example would just become:

```
export class JSONParser extends stream.Transform {

    constructor() {
        super({objectMode: true, readableHighWaterMark: 5, writableHighWaterMark: 3}); // 5 on the readable side, 3 on the writable
    }
}
```

Please note that if `highWaterMark` is set, it will override `readableHighWaterMark` or `writableHighWaterMark` (source: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/864860e9f3d4eed0b0b81af55197d7e525ea6306/lib/internal/streams/state.js).